# to make progress bar for file upload in jsp

Tags: jsp

I am novice in jsp. I have to make a tomcat website which will allow uploading of files in sequence. 
How to create progress bar for upload?
How to design sequential upload of file?

Comment: jsp alone isn't going to be enough, you need ajax.

Comment: Did you see ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet?rq=1

Comment: I am able to upload , but how to assign a progress bar to it?

Comment: If you use Apache Commons FileUpload, then you can use their ProgressListener.  Look at bottom of page at  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html